# What is the difference between the field lookup and the function lookup?

Tags: delphi, ado

Is there any difference in performance or another difference or are both the same thing (as per the lookup fields in the TADOquery and TCustomADODataSet)?

I have read the Help files, but I didn't found anything explaining on this.

Comment: `Lookup()` is the function called from lookup fields to fill their values.

Comment: @pagenotfound, shouldn't that be the answer?

Comment: @PageNotFound In the function lookup I can put key fields, key values and result fields, but in the lookup field I can put, for example, DataSet. This is what caused my confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Lookup()` function is a virtual function of `TDataSet`.

Being a virtual function means that the implementation can change from class to class.

Because of this, the documentation has different comments that varies from each `TDataSet` descendant.

Let's take a closer look:

- `TDataSet`'s `Lookup()`:

> Implements a virtual method to retrieve field values from a record
>   that matches specified search values.

See more [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Lookup)

**Note this remark at the end of the document:**

> Descendant classes that are not unidirectional override this method so
>   that it locates the record where the fields identified by the
>   comma-delimited string KeyFields have the values specified by the
>   Variant or Variant array KeyValues. In classes that implement Lookup,
>   it returns a Variant or Variant array that contains the value or
>   values of the fields specified by the comma-delimited string
>   ResultFields on the specified record.

---

- `TCustomADODataSet`'s `Lookup()`:

Here, the remark above is happening in pratice. Note, in this implementation there is no call to `inherited.`

The Documentation says:

> Retrieves field values from a row that matches specified search
>   values.

Details [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.Lookup)

---

Now, you can only understand the difference by digging into the source code. At the end, you will note that there is no difference at all. You will realise that the lookup fields will just call `Lookup()` function:

### 1. A lookup field is like a calculated field.

- Is affected by the `AutoCalcFields` property (See [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.AutoCalcFields))
- The same function the fires `OnCalcFields` event is responsible for
  calling `CalcLookupValue`
- `UniDirectional` DataSet also do not have `Lookup` Fields. (See
  [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.IsUniDirectional))

### 2. The `Lookup` Field calls the `Lookup()` Function

- On this, there is no documentation, you will have to see for yourself: 
  `procedure TField.CalcLookupValue;`
- The `Lookup()` arguments is filled with the `TField` properties: `FLookupDataSet.Lookup(FLookupKeyFields,
  FDataSet.FieldValues[FKeyFields], FLookupResultField);`

The `Lookup()` function consumes all related properties from the lookup field, as you can see above:

- FKeyFields = TField.KeyFields
- FLookupDataSet = TField.LookupDataSet
- FLookupKeyFields = TField.LookupKeyFields
- FLookupResultField = TField.LookupResultField